# Can XSLT or XPath handle an empty file?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have an file which will either be empty, or will contain a single line with a single string value.

I can consume the file contents in either an XPath expression evaluator or in an XSL transform, version 1.

I simply need to know if there is a value in the file or not.

As far as I know, both tools require correctly formed XML.

Do I have any options?

(It's a boring story about why I only have XPath or XSLT 1.0 available to me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that XPath and XSLT generally operate on well-formed XML, and an empty file is not well formed XML because it lacks a single root element.

XSLT 2.0, however, can read non-XML via [**`unparsed-text()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#function-unparsed-text).  That's your ticket for exploring empty or any other text that's not well-formed XML using XSLT.

If you only have XSLT 1.0, then you're out of luck if you can't operate outside of XSLT 1.0 via preprocessing or using non-standard extensions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Sadly, I am working within an existing framework and XSLT 1 is my only option :(

Comment: Then as you anticipated, you're out of luck.  Sorry.  Answer updated to make that more clear.